# Match regular expression to string

Tags: javascript

I am having a text and would like to get all occurrences in an array, such as:

```
[
    ['{{ $slot }}'],
    ['{{$example }}'],
    ['{{ $Product2}}'],
    ['{{$category1 }}']
]
```

I tried the following example:

```js
const text = "<h1>Hello world!</h1> <h2>What is {{ $slot }} Ipsum?</h2> <p><strong>Lorem Ipsum</strong> is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry&#39;s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to {{$example }}make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially {{$category1 }} unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more {{ $Product2}} recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p> <p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p>"

let data = text.match('/{{\s*\$\w+\s*}}')

console.log(data)
```

As you can see I get `null` as result.

Any suggestions why?

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: You're matching against a string, not a regular expression. Also, if that were a regular expression it would be invalid. Need to escape those curly braces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In JavaScript, a [regexp literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) is different from a [string literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String), so the argument of `match` must be `/{{\s*\$\w+\s*}}/` and not `'{{\s*\$\w+\s*}}'` or `'/{{\s*\$\w+\s*}}'`. Notice that there is no quotes around it. So try:

```
const text = "<h1>Hello world!</h1> <h2>What is {{ $slot }} Ipsum?</h2> <p><strong>Lorem Ipsum</strong> is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry&#39;s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to {{$example }}make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially {{$category1 }} unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more {{ $Product2}} recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p> <p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p>"
let data = /{{\s*\$\w+\s*}}/g
```

Which gives:

```
>>> data
Array(4) [
    "{{ $slot }}",
    "{{ $example }}",
    "{{ $category1 }}",
    "{{ $Product2}}"
]
```

Note that I added the `g` flag after the final slash of the regexp for the match to return all the matching strings and not only the first one.

As others noticed, it is also a good practice to escape the curly brackets, otherwise you would run into trouble when they will contain a number, as this has a special meaning for regexps.

Comment: Fixed that for you :D

Answer (score 1):

try without the first slash

'{{\s*\$\w+\s*}}'

[regex101 example](https://regex101.com/r/945JTS/1)

Match 1

> Full match 35-46   `{{ $slot }}`

Match 2

> Full match 302-315 `{{$example }}`

Match 3

> Full match 452-467 `{{$category1 }}`

Match 4

> Full match 589-603 `{{ $Product2}}`

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following ([see regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/cc4jfX/1)):

```
const text = "<h1>Hello world!</h1> <h2>What is {{ $slot }} Ipsum?</h2> <p><strong>Lorem Ipsum</strong> is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry&#39;s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to {{$example }}make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially {{$category1 }} unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more {{ $Product2}} recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p> <p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p>";

let regex = /\{\{\s*(\$[\w_]+)\s*\}\}/g;

let data = text.match(regex);
console.log(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use a [**RegExp literal**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) and:

- escape the `$` via `\$` to match literally the `$` character and don't assert the end of the line position in the middle of the regular expression by accident
- use the `g` global match flag to match every occurrence in the string

[**More on available flags and character classes**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#character-classes)

---

**So the final regex is:**

```
/{{\s*\$\w+\s*}}/g
```

---

#### Working Example:

```js
const text = '<h1>Hello world!</h1> <h2>What is {{ $slot }} Ipsum?</h2> <p><strong>Lorem Ipsum</strong> is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry&#39;s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to {{$example }}make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially {{$category1 }} unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more {{ $Product2}} recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p> <p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p>'

let data = text.match(/{{\s*\$\w+\s*}}/g)

console.log(data)
```

#### OR

...via [**RegExp constructor**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions), just make sure to properly escape the [**RegExp character classes**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#character-classes) and already present `\` characters via a leading `\`:

```js
const text = '<h1>Hello world!</h1> <h2>What is {{ $slot }} Ipsum?</h2> <p><strong>Lorem Ipsum</strong> is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry&#39;s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to {{$example }}make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially {{$category1 }} unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more {{ $Product2}} recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p> <p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p>'

let data = text.match(new RegExp('{{\\s*\\$\\w+\\s*}}', 'g'))

console.log(data)
```